# Under which circumstances is it fine to drop armv6 support?

Tags: ios, xcode, armv7, armv6

I want to use a framework which recommends to disable armv6 support in Xcode. Though I am not sure what consequences this has.

As I understand so far, any device older or slower than a 3GS does not have armv7 and only armv6. So when I drop support for armv6 I assume my app binary becomes smaller and it will stop running on these old devices?

If you drop armv6 support do you need to specify anything else for required device capabilities to exclude devices that only have armv6?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can target your app for `armv7` and above which uses certain device hardware capabilities that do not exist on `armv6` devices.

To do this, it is required that you add `armv7` in the [*Required Device Capabilities (UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities)*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3) key in the project’s `Info.plist` file.

> UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities (Array or Dictionary - iOS) lets iTunes and the App Store know which device-related features an app requires in order to run. iTunes and the mobile App Store use this list to prevent customers from installing apps on a device that does not support the listed capabilities.

**Unrelated but Important Note**: [UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities Cannot Be Changed in App Updates](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/12/uirequireddevicecapabilities-cannot-be-changed-in-app-updates/).
So if your app supports `armv6` you cannot submit a new update to restrict archs from `armv7` and above.

Hope that helps!